# Remove accidental rollback to previous revision

Tags: support, revisions

In this question [Does Windows Firewall fully block Windows Telemetry?](https://superuser.com/q/1207878/), I wanted to edit my answer. But suddenly my PC's cursor glitches and I clicked to rollback and delete option of that answer.

Now that answer shows extra versions of those faulty revisions/deletions. Can I remove those notifications? Or Can moderators remove those three extra revision notifications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but no. Moderators cannot delete revision history on answers or questions. It's only minor noise and does not *need* to be deletable.

If you have a ***really*** good reason to want them gone then contacting the community team might be an option. Just "I don't like garbage in the history" isn't really a good reason though.

Comment: Ya, I thought that it will be irritating to have useless revision in SE. I wanted to add more info in that answer. Can I add now?

Comment: Noting to stop you improving your answer. The revision history is just that: history.

Comment: It is also an audit trail.  Which is the reason will not be modified outside of a retraction of personal identification information (i.e. your home phone number, etc) that was submitted by mistake.

Comment: While you are correct in that this is not a situation where revisions should be erased, you are incorrect in that mods *can* redact revisions as of recent changes. It takes two mods: one to propose the redaction, and another to approve it.

Comment: @gparyani I am completely aware of what I can and cannot do as a moderator. Redacting revisions is completely unrelated and irrelevant to outright deleting them.

Comment: @gparyani I am also not incorrect about saying moderators cannot redact revisions because I never mentioned redacting revisions at all. The question was specifically about **deleting** revisions which we simply cannot do. If the question here was "can you remove personal information from the revisions" then my answer would have been "sure, me and another mod can do that". But this is not what this question was asking and I told you exactly what we cannot do: We cannot delete **revisions**.